# Java odds calculator layout

Tags: java

I'm making a poker odds calculator in Java. My desired layout is something like this(labels showing the odds below each player now shown)

[image]

The rectangles above the table are all Card objects extending JButton. The rectangles under the players and on the table are Card objects too. The new hand shape is as normal JButton. Dead cards are also Card objects. The table itself is a JLabel. I read about the different layouts but I don't know which one to use (for the JFrame and JPanel). As you can see I also need to place some components on top of each other. What the best way to setup the layout here? Multiple panels, null layout?

Below the code where you can see how I create a `Card` and add it (I do this 52x). And you can see how I add the table and the player 1 spot 1 `Card`

```
public class OddsCalculator extends JFrame{

JPanel cardsPanel;
JLabel tablePicture;

Card aceClubs;
Card kingClubs;
Card queenClubs;
Card jackClubs;
Card tenClubs;
Card nineClubs;
Card eightClubs;
Card sevenClubs;
Card sixClubs;
Card fiveClubs;
Card fourClubs;
Card threeClubs;
Card twoClubs;

//spades
Card aceSpades;
Card kingSpades;
Card queenSpades;
Card jackSpades;
Card tenSpades;
Card nineSpades;
Card eightSpades;
Card sevenSpades;
Card sixSpades;
Card fiveSpades;
Card fourSpades;
Card threeSpades;
Card twoSpades;

//hearts
Card aceHearts;
Card kingHearts;
Card queenHearts;
Card jackHearts;
Card tenHearts;
Card nineHearts;
Card eightHearts;
Card sevenHearts;
Card sixHearts;
Card fiveHearts;
Card fourHearts;
Card threeHearts;
Card twoHearts;

//diamonds
Card aceDiamonds;
Card kingDiamonds;
Card queenDiamonds;
Card jackDiamonds;
Card tenDiamonds;
Card nineDiamonds;
Card eightDiamonds;
Card sevenDiamonds;
Card sixDiamonds;
Card fiveDiamonds;
Card fourDiamonds;
Card threeDiamonds;
Card twoDiamonds;

Card playerOneCardOne;

public OddsCalculator(){
    initUI();
}


public void initUI() {;
   setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
   cardsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
   tablePicture = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(Constants.POKERTABLE_ICON)));

   aceClubs=new Card();
   kingClubs=new Card();
   queenClubs=new Card();
   jackClubs=new Card();
   tenClubs=new Card();
   nineClubs=new Card();
   eightClubs=new Card();
   sevenClubs=new Card();
   sixClubs=new Card();
   fiveClubs=new Card();
   fourClubs=new Card();
   threeClubs=new Card();
   twoClubs=new Card();

   aceSpades=new Card();
   kingSpades=new Card();
   queenSpades=new Card();
   jackSpades=new Card();
   tenSpades=new Card();
   nineSpades=new Card();
   eightSpades=new Card();
   sevenSpades=new Card();
   sixSpades=new Card();
   fiveSpades=new Card();
   fourSpades=new Card();
   threeSpades=new Card();
   twoSpades=new Card();

   aceHearts=new Card();
   kingHearts=new Card();
   queenHearts=new Card();
   jackHearts=new Card();
   tenHearts=new Card();
   nineHearts=new Card();
   eightHearts=new Card();
   sevenHearts=new Card();
   sixHearts=new Card();
   fiveHearts=new Card();
   fourHearts=new Card();
   threeHearts=new Card();
   twoHearts=new Card();

   aceDiamonds=new Card();
   kingDiamonds=new Card();
   queenDiamonds=new Card();
   jackDiamonds=new Card();
   tenDiamonds=new Card();
   nineDiamonds=new Card();
   eightDiamonds=new Card();
   sevenDiamonds=new Card();
   sixDiamonds=new Card();
   fiveDiamonds=new Card();
   fourDiamonds=new Card();
   threeDiamonds=new Card();
   twoDiamonds=new Card();

   playerOneCardOne=new Card();

   //setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

   cardsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200,800));//was 1000/600

   getContentPane().add(cardsPanel);

   //setSize(1000,1600);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


   aceClubs.suit=Constants.CARD_SUIT_CLUBS;
   aceClubs.kind=Constants.CARD_KIND_ACE;
   aceClubs.iconPath=Constants.ACE_CLUBS_ICON;

   aceClubs.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(aceClubs.iconPath)));
   aceClubs.setBorder(null);
   aceClubs.setContentAreaFilled(false);
   aceClubs.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
   cardsPanel.add(aceClubs);

   cardsPanel.add(tablePicture); //add the table

   //PLAYER 1 CARD SPOTS
   playerOneCardOne.iconPath=Constants.CARD_BACKSIDE;
   playerOneCardOne.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(playerOneCardOne.iconPath)));
   playerOneCardOne.setBorder(null);
   playerOneCardOne.setContentAreaFilled(false);
   playerOneCardOne.setLocation(new Point(100,100));
   cardsPanel.add(playerOneCardOne);
}

 private void MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)   {                              

     JButton b=(JButton)evt.getSource();
     System.out.println("Location: "+b.getLocation());
     b.setVisible(false);

}              

public static void main(String[] args) {
  OddsCalculator oc=new OddsCalculator();
  oc.setVisible(true);
  oc.pack();      
  }
 }
```

Card.cs

```
public class Card extends JButton{
int suit;
int kind;
boolean known;
String iconPath;
}
```

Comment: Well, your luck is that you have 52 cards. I want to see your code for 52 thousand cards. Will it be 1000 times longer?

Comment: The big picture looks like a BorderLayout with the with the cards in NORTH, the table and associated "middle" stuff in CENTER, and the dead cards in SOUTH.

Comment: @AlexR Yes it would, had to find another way then. For 52 card this is okay , I think.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils what layout do I use for the JFrame?

Comment: If that's the entirety of the content use the border layout there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `BorderLayout`, `b1`,  with the cards in the top pane (`PAGE_START`), dead cards in the bottom pane (`PAGE_END`) and a `BorderLayout`, b2, in the center (`CENTER`) pane. The left and right panes of `b1` will be empty.

Place the table in the center pane of `b2`, and the players in the top, bottom, left (`LINE_START`) and right (`LINE_END`) panes.

Place the "New Hand" widget by adding an appropriate layoutmanager to the `b2.LINE_START` pane. `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout` will probably be a good choice.

I have used the AWT/Swing names for the layout managers. If you opt to use JavaFX instead, simply switch to the JavaFX equivalents:

AWT: `BorderLayout` = JavaFX: `BorderPane`

AWT: `GridLayout`/`GridBagLayout` = JavaFX: `GridPane`

In JavaFX, use a `StackPane` to place widgets on top of each other.

Links:

[AWT/Swing Layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

[JavaFX Layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. Is it possible to place components on top of each other in the center pane with BorderLayout.? So your idea is to set a BorderLayout for the panel, but which Layout do I use for the JFrame? Or do you mean a frame with BorderLayout containing 3 panes?